# Где границы деепричастного оборота?

Tags: и, синтаксис, пунктуация

**Вирус гуляет по планете, вызывая вспышки заболевания у птиц - уже более четырёхсот случаев.**

Как вы считаете, нужна ли запятая перед тире? Можно ли рассматривать "уже более четырёх случаев"  как присоединительную конструкцию, входящую в ДО? (В задании нужно расставить знаки препинания, но тире уже поставлено).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, имеется в виду, что запятую надо поставить. Предложение в таком виде имеет неясное прочтение, а мы не должны забывать о том, что наша пунктуация должна отражать все три принципа(семантический, грамматический и интонационный).

Получаем: Вирус гуляет по планете, вызывая вспышки заболевания у птиц, - уже более четырёхсот случаев. Но и в таком виде предложение вызывает сомнения: получается, что мы нарушаем семантический принцип (отнесенность обособленного оборота к ДО).

Хотелось бы предложение переделать, например:

Вирус гуляет по планете, вызывая вспышки заболевания у птиц (уже более четырёхсот случаев).

Вирус гуляет по планете, вызывая вспышки заболевания у птиц,  - отмечено уже более четырёхсот случаев. В этом случае это БСП, второе предложение имеет присоединительный характер.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Действительно, хотелось бы переделать предложение. Думается, некорректно давать такой спорный случай в демонстрационном варианте итоговой работы за 10 класс ( Статград).